# Styling drop down list selected item

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net-4.5, dropdown

I checked for this before posting here and didn't find anything for my problem.

I have a drop down list to which I manually append an item at the end. I want to use some other color for this item, say red, to distinguish it from other items. I can do this part. However, when I select the item, the text in the drop down's selected item is not red. I am not sure if there is any way to access it in order to apply style to it.

This is what I used (assuming the "value" of this last item in drop down is 0):

```
ListItem li = ddl1.Items.FindByValue("0");

if (null != li)
{
    li.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
}
```

the above works coloring last item red. The following didn't work when I select this last item and want the selected item to displayed in the same red color:

```
ListItem li = ddl1.Items.FindByValue("0");

if (null != li)
{
    li.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");

    if (li.Selected)
        ddl1.SelectedItem.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
    else
        ddl1.SelectedItem.Attributes.Add("style", "color:black");
}
```

Neither did this (this actually colors all list items red if I select the last item):

```
ListItem li = ddl1.Items.FindByValue("0");

if (null != li)
{
    li.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
    ddl1.Style["color"] = "red";
}
```

Comment: can you use CSS?  I can provide an example using CSS, giving more flexibility than inline style

Comment: I believe I can; instead of li.Attributes.Add ("style, "color:red") I should be able to do li.Attrinutes.Add ("class", "myDDL"). My issue is styling the item that shows in drop down when you select an item from the list and the list collapses and you only see the selected item. That item that is being displayed to use as selected item, I cannot style; don't know how to access it.

Comment: are you missing the "AutoPostback = true" property in your ddl1.properties?

Answer (score 0):

to use a pure CSS way, add this CSS

```
#ddl1>option:checked  {
  background-color: red;
}
```

and in your C#, you can add and select the new option.  Let me know if this needs to change course

Comment: Thanks. This applies the style to ALL drop down lists and to any selected item (which is nice). But what I am looking for is this: you expand drop down, you select an item, drop down list collapses and your selected item is displayed to user. THIS is the item I am trying to access. And I don;t want to do it to all items, only if the item I had appended to drop don list manually is selected (with value of "0").